# How does Citrix DaaS know who is connected to a particular virtual desktop

Tags: citrix

How does Citrix DaaS know who is connected to a particular virtual desktop?

The question is related to porting Windows .NET desktop applications (Winforms) to the cloud using Citrix DaaS. These applications must know **who** is using them, and at present they rely on this .NET call:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

which returns {DOMAIN-NAME}/{WINDOWS-USER-LOGON}

And what if there are two shifts, day-shift and night-shift, and employees share virtual desktops so that the virtual desktop is not dedicated to a single employee?

Comment: Hi, I´m not sure if I got this correctly. A user connects to a virtual desktop (VDI) and uses an application where that must know who is using them, right? But you want to know where Citrix get this information from, right?

Comment: @AzureBaum:  I need to know whether, on a virtual desktop, that call to `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdenity.GetCurrent().Name` will return the domain identity of the authenticated user, e.g. `MYDOMAIN/johndoe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could test and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent?view=net-5.0) confirmed:

The current logged on user in .NET with the format 'NetworkName\Username' will be returned with `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`

Comment: The tests were on Citrix VDI? And the username returned is a "real" and persistent one (e.g. ACMEWIDGETS\marysmith) not a system-generated identity?

Comment: I tried it on a Windows 10 citrix VDI and it returned the current logged on user like this: ‚contoso\karlome‘. Does this not work for you?

Comment: Thanks, that would work. I don't have a system to test on here and it's not clear whether the company pitching the solution would give us the opportunity to do a proof-of-concept. I have certainly asked for that.